Plugins between OpenLiberty and Apache
I would like to link OpenLiberty and Apache with a plugin, but I think I have to load the plugin file and module generated by OpenLiberty into Apache. Is there a plug-in load module available on OpenLiberty?
OpenLibertyから公開されているロードModuleを探しております。

You can use the same WebSphere WebServer Plug-in for Apache HTTP Server that you may have used with WebSphere Application Server (traditional) or WebSphere Liberty with Open Liberty.
The basics are:

Install the WebSphere Web Server Plug-in
Optional: Install and run PCT. With Apache and Liberty, PCT does not do much more than create a few directories and append a few lines to httpd.conf.  Tell PCT you are configuring a "remote" application server and ignore the generated configurewebserver1.sh

Configure the Open Liberty server.xml to tell it where the Plug-in is installed:


<pluginConfiguration pluginInstallRoot="/opt/IBM/plugin">


From a running Open Liberty server with applications installed, use the bin/pluginUtility generate to generate a plugin-cfg.xml in your working directory
Transfer plugin-cfg.xml to the appropriate place on the webserver system
Generate a plugin-key.kdb on the webserver system and add the trusted certificate authority (or self-signed generated certs) liberty uses.
$ gskcapicmd -keydb -create -db /opt/IBM/pluin/config/webserver1/plugin-key.kdb -stash
$ keytool -exportcert -rfc -alias default -file /tmp/ca-$HOSTNAME.cert - keystore usr/servers/defaultServer/resources/security/key.p12
$ gskcapicmd -cert -add -db /opt/plugin/config/webserver1/plugin-key.kdb -stashed -label ca-host1 -file /tmp/ca-$HOSTNAME.cert



You can of course also use the generic proxy support provided by Apache, but there is very little websphere-specific to configure:

If using mod_proxy_balancer, you would specify stickysession=JSESSIONID stickysessionsep=: and then list route=xxx for each cloneID being used by Liberty.
You may find it convenient to specify long-lived cloneIDs via server.xml: <httpSession cloneId="node1"/>


